# Pie chart without text inside

Tags: vb.net, charts

How to draw a pie chart but i don't want to have the Name Values inside it. I draw a chart with legend like this.

```
       With Me.chrtRegisterAvailability
        .Legends.Clear()
        .Series.Clear()
        .ChartAreas.Clear()
    End With

    Dim areas1 As ChartArea = Me.chrtRegisterAvailability.ChartAreas.Add("Areas1")

    With areas1
    End With

    Dim series1 As Series = Me.chrtRegisterAvailability.Series.Add("Series1")

    With series1
        .ChartArea = areas1.Name
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
        .Points.AddXY("Website Impressions", TextBox1.Text)
        .Points.AddXY("Social Media", TextBox2.Text)
        .Points.AddXY("Clicks", textbox3.text)
    End With

    Dim legends1 As Legend = Me.chrtRegisterAvailability.Legends.Add("Legends1")
End Sub
```

And it looks like this "[Picture](http://pokit.org/get/?1b1843bf3a5bbd7854963b2ab8a449ce.jpg)  I want chart without this text inside.

Problem #2. Is there any way i can send this Chart from Form1 to rdlc. MS Report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chartName.Series(0)("PieLabelStyle") = "Disabled"
```

Comment: I also want to add % instead text in pie chart is that possible ?

Comment: Do you know how to add % instead

Comment: I'm not sure, but a quick search yielded me: `chartName.Series("Series1").Label = "#PERCENT"` and this: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2008/11/11/microsoft-chart-control-how-to-using-keywords.aspx)

Comment: awesome work i just need to figure more how to display different legend it shows me in legend percent also :( :( 
http://pokit.org/get/?b0383e75d2de96010e5141e917eb5375.jpg

Comment: I imagine all of that info you'll find on that link I posted above. I don't know enough about charts to be more help, sorry

Comment: Yea i found it very useful thanks for helping me in this. Once again